# Issues With SOQL query returning no records

Tags: apex, soql

Okay i have been looking at this code a while now however i am not sure why my user list is not being populated. IN my debug logs I am getting the values for lstOCRScreenedEmails which is - test@gmail.com, Test2@gmail.com however when it queries the user object there are no results. If I use Workbench and run the query records return.....

```
List<ApprovalEmails__mdt> lstsobjOCRScreenedEmails = ([
    SELECT ApprovalEmails__c 
    FROM ApprovalEmails__mdt 
    WHERE label = 'OCR Screened'
]);

List<String> lstOCRScreenedEmails = new List<String> ();

for (ApprovalEmails__mdt Approvals: lstsobjOCRScreenedEmails) {
    lstOCRScreenedEmails.add(String.valueOf(Approvals.ApprovalEmails__c));
}

System.debug(Logginglevel.DEBUG , 'My Debug lstOCRScreenedEmails  :' + lstOCRScreenedEmails);

List<User> user = ([
    SELECT email, firstName, lastName 
    FROM User 
    WHERE email IN: lstOCRScreenedEmails
]);

System.debug(Logginglevel.DEBUG , 'My Debug user  :' + user);
```

Comment: O this work with 1 email address but not 2 email address.......

Comment: Additionally I created a list manually and used the SQL and it works fine List<String> myList = new 
    List<String>();
     myList.add('test@gmail.com,');  
     myList.add('Test2@gmail.com');

Comment: Instead of just saying you did a debug and you see that it is right, please copy/paste the exact line from the debug log and allow us to look at it as it may reveal additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
lstOCRScreenedEmails.add(String.valueOf(Approvals.ApprovalEmails__c));
```

Try

```
lstOCRScreenedEmails.add(Approvals.ApprovalEmails__c);
```

ApprovalEmails__c implies there is more than 1 email. If this is a csv type field you'll want to split that out into multiple sub-strings:

```
for (String email : Approvals.ApprovalEmails__c.split(',')) {
    lstOCRScreenedEmails.add(email);
}
```

If you can provide the debug output from your debug statements, I can review them and see if there is anything else they reveal.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was expecting multiple emails. Thank you